# I don't understand ifstream

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

In my textbook it says that `ifstream` is an `istream` for reading from a file. Later down the page, there is a comment next to an example:

```
ifstream ist(name.c_str()); // ist is an input stream for the file named name.
```

I'm a little confused what the difference is between `ifstream` and `ist()`.

Comment: `ifstream` is the type, `ist` is the variable name. This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: `std::ifstream` is a class and `ist` is an instance of the class.

Comment: I figured ist was the variable name. But they way they worded it made it seem like you have to use ist and I had seen a lot of other people use it. Is that just a convention to use it?

Comment: @UnworthyToast I would say it's just an abbreviation for "Input stream"

Comment: @UnworthyToast I've personally never seen `ist` as a variable name for a file stream. You can use what you want but I would advise choosing variable names that are easy to understand and express your intent succinctly.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I tend to use `ifile` personally.

Comment: For some more ideas, I tend to prefer `fin` to make it resemble `cin` or `ifs` as an abbreviation.

Answer (score 3):

`ist` is the instance of `ifstream` you will be using. There is a type - `ifstream` - which can be the type of many variables.

You could have `ist`, `ist2`, `ist3`, `xpto`, all of them being an `ifstream`.

`ifstream` is the type.